# Scroll to particular Item using ID of that item in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was Trying to scroll to particular row item in react using ID of that item. I have the ID of particular row but not able to move there.

```
goToViolation=(id)=>{
  const violation = id ; 
  window.scrollTo({
    top:violation.current.offsetTop,
    behavior:"smooth"});
};

 if (isDrillDown) {
        isRowSelected = index === rowIndex % 20;
       if(isRowSelected){
        this.goToViolation(row.id);
       }
      }
```

1. i was getting the ID from this Condition and i am passing it to the above function and using scrollTo function.

Comment: what does violation refer to? individual rows?

Answer (score 7):

In order to scroll to an element you need ref for that element.

`<div onClick={this.goToViolation("row-id")} id="row-id"></div>`

Then in your function

```
goToViolation=(id)=>{
  const violation = document.getElementById(id); 
  window.scrollTo({
    top:violation.offsetTop,
    behavior:"smooth"
});
};
```

Comment: I don't think so it's a ref, please share the full code

Comment: http://pastie.org/p/1ZPyBLI3IHSbVg1UOW8q65
this is code link

Comment: The problem is all of yours have same refs, this won't allow you to scroll.

Comment: Please use this code

 <TableRow
              hover={true}
              role='checkbox'
              aria-checked={isItemSelected}
              tabIndex={id}
              key={id}
              id={id}
              selected={isRowSelected || isItemSelected}
              classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}
              className={{ 'blink': isRowSelected }}
              ref={reference}
            ></TableRow>

Then above mentioned code

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @MuhammadAsad that manipulating the DOM directly is not a React way.

Instead you can use `useRef` hook and pass the ref to your JSX element.

After that, you can collect the DOM reference from `.current` property.

Then you can just do

```
**your ref**.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });
```

Example,

Your variable declaration.

```
const violationRef = useRef(null);
```

Your JSX element which you want to scroll to.

```
<div ref={violationRef} ></div>
```

Your button which will bind onClick event.

```
<button onClick={goToViolation} />
```

Your handler function

```
const goToViolation=(id)=>{
  violationRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end" });
};
```

Comment: but there is no button for me to call the function in onclick prop, actually im drilling down to the current page from another page selecting particular item, so it should show the same item there.

Comment: no problem if the event handler goToViolation and the ref is not from same component. just pass the ref out of the component using event props. and use the ref from another component.

Comment: `<TableRow
              hover={true}
              role='checkbox'
              aria-checked={isItemSelected}
              tabIndex={id}
              key={id}
              selected={isRowSelected || isItemSelected}
              classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}
              className={{ 'blink': isRowSelected }}
              ref={this.violationRef}
            >`
i used the code which you suggest, but not able to call the goToViolation function through the element "TableRow"

Comment: no it is from the same component but which prop should i use in the element TableRow to call the function. I am very beginner to this field please don't mine if my questions were silly

Comment: are you clicking the TableRow  to trigger? if you are , put onClick event on TableRow and then bind the goToViolation function. no worries, we are here to help.

Comment: it will be better if you can provide a sandbox environment like stackblitz or playcode or codesandbox , then it is easier for everyone to fully understand the problem.

Comment: can you please go through this link and check my code.

http://pastie.org/p/1ZPyBLI3IHSbVg1UOW8q65

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220396/discussion-between-hemanth-kumar-and-kevin-moe-myint-myat).